# tracepath and too many hops on ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 14.04, traceroute

I have got three Ubuntu servers (virtual) running in cloud, they all are sitting in the same virtual LAN and configured with similar specs. However when I run `tracepath` on those three hosts to a specific target host, one of them comes out with strange output saying `too many hops` whereas the other two can can reach the target with 2 hops.

In fact it should be the same number of hops on all of them, any ideas what could be the issue here? Does the network stack needs a restart?

Working:

```
root@xx-yy-zz-02:~# tracepath target.mail.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.32.2                                           1.797ms
 1:  192.168.32.2                                           1.694ms
 2:  target.mail.com                                     3.075ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 2 back 2
```

Not working:

```
root@xx-yy-zz-01:/var/log# tracepath target.mail.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  no reply
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply
 6:  no reply
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1500
     Resume: pmtu 1500
```

Routing configuration looks same on both the hosts, network team points at the virtual server itself.

Comment: I'd wager on a bug in tracepath. Use "mtr" instead: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/mtr.8.html

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind, I will give it a try and let you know. We also had mail timeout issues on the same virtual host where the mail times out after 5 minutes .

Comment: mtr seems to have the same thing but definitely better tool. I have tried running tracepath with different packet size and it seems to get no response from the next hop when the packet size is 1460.